# LINQ filter list in list by a specific term

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I know it has been discussed a lot, but, being a beginner in LINQ I don't manage to filter this situation:

I have a list of `Customers` containing a list of `Projects`

list to filter:

```
List<Customer> Customers {get; set;}
```

this is Customer class:

```
class Customer
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public List<Project> Projects {get; set;}
}
```

this is Project class:

```
class Project
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

All I want is to find all customers containing **ONLY** the projects that have a certain name (my app will filter by the project's name).

As for now I have this:

```
Customers
    .Where(c => c.Projects.Any(p => p.Name.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(lowerCaseFilter)));
```

but it doesn't help, because it will return all the customers containing **ALL** the projects not only the one I have searched.

For example, if I have a list of 15 customers with an unknown number of projects in each of them, I want to display only those customers and **only** those projects in every customers that meet the searched term.

I think I am missing something here...

Comment: instead of c.Projects.Any, why not c.Projects.Where?

Comment: What data type is "lowerCaseFilter" ?

Comment: lowerCaseFilter is the search terrm coming from a textbox

Comment: Maybe changing `c.Projects.Any` to `c.Projects.All` is what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to recreate the customers and the projects if you want to modify the list:

```
var searchedCustomers = Customers
    .Select(c => new { 
        Customer = c,
        FilteredProjects = c.Projects
            .Where(p => string.Equals(p.Name, nameFilter, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            .ToList()
    })
    .Where(x => x.FilteredProjects.Any())
    .Select(x => new Customer{ 
        Name = x.Customer.Name,  
        Projects = x.FilteredProjects 
    });
```

I've used [`String.Equals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4411bks(v=vs.110).aspx) with `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` to avoid creating lower case strings and to avoid some localization issues like the [turkish i problem](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/07/05/turkish-i-problem-and-why-you-should-care.aspx/). So you also don't need the `lowerCaseFilter` with this approach so i've named it `nameFilter`.

Comment: Yeap, this worked for me :) The hint with the recreation of the lists made light in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var customers = Customers
            .Select(c => new Customer() { Name = c.Name, Projects = c.Projects == null ? new List<Project>() : c.Projects.Where(p => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Name) && p.Name.ToLower().Contains(lowerCaseFilter)).ToList() })
            .Where(c => c.Projects.Any())
            .ToList();
```

You will have to create new Customer objects that only contain the projects that you want.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by

> it will return all the customers containing ALL the projects not only
>   the one I have searched.

I can interpret that in two ways, please clarify:

- You want to return all customers that have at least one project with the specified name, and exclude the nonmatching projects from the final results (a)
- You want to return only those customers that have projects matching the filter and no other projects (b) (In other words if *any* of the projects doesn't match the filter, then that customer should be left out regardless of whether or not it has a matching project).

Solution for (a):

```
Customers
  .Where(c => c.Projects.Any(p => p.Name.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(lowerCaseFilter)))
  .Select(c => new Customer
  {
    // set all other properties
    Projects = c.Projects
      .Where(p => p.Name.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(lowerCaseFiler))
      .ToList()
  });
```

What you do here is simply filter the `Projects` collection of the result by the desired value.

Solution for (b):

```
Customers
  .Where(c => c.Projects.All(p => p.Name.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(lowerCaseFilter)))
```

This simply filters the customers collection for those items that only contain projects which match the desired filter.